# TeXworks linux vs windows

Tags: bibtex, windows, ubuntu, texworks

I have some documents that require extensive use of BibTeX files, and on the windows version of TeXworks there is the possibility of running `pdflateX+MakeIndex+BibTeX`, which is not present in the linux version (I am using ubuntu). I have to separately run BibTeX and the LaTeX compilers so that I can update my citations, which is a bit of a hassle. Is there any way to manually add the `pdflateX+MakeIndex+BibTeX` mode to TeXworks under linux?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

create a little bash script for the three commands, put it into `~/bin/` and then create a new menu option inside TeXworks (Edit->Preferences).

Answer (score 3):

MiKTeX on Windows includes a program called `texify` which does the combined pdfLaTeX, MakeIndex and BibTeX run. There is not an identical program on Linux, but there are several scripting systems for LaTeX. As Herbert has said, you could write a simple script to do the job, but if you are not a scripting person might want to look at for example [`latexmk`](http://www.phys.psu.edu/~collins/software/latexmk-jcc/) (which just 'does stuff') or [`arara`](https://github.com/cereda/arara) (which is more user-controlled).

Comment: `latexmk` is already installed in TeXWorks

Comment: @Herbert Depends on how you get TeXworks: the 'vanilla' one does not include it.

Comment: Ah ok, didn't know that

Comment: then just adding latexmk to the typesetting tools in teXworks should be enough for it to work?

Comment: @joaocandre: for TeXLive yes, it is already installed. You can test it with `which latexmk`